# trying to send some data to a JSP page from GWT

Tags: gwt

I have a GWT Application where i am getting some data from RPC.

So i have

```
String data = "someData";
```

Now I have a JSP page where I like to send this "data".

I am currently opening my JSP Page like this from within my GWT Client side.

```
Window.open("Test.jsp","","");
```

In my JSP Page I have

```
<%= new String("Hello!") %>
```

Now Is it possible to send that "data" from GWT to this Jsp Page .
So my Jsp will say

```
Hello! someData
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Window.open("Test.jsp?data=someData","","");
```

to pass parameters to your JSP (in this example parameter name `data` and value `someData`.
To fetch the parameter inside a JSP you would use

```
${param.data}
```

For a servlet you can use

```
String value = request.getParameter("data");
```

to do the same.

Note that URL parameter values (like `someData` in the example above) need to be properly escaped. GWT has the `com.google.gwt.http.client.URL` class for that:

```
String value = "someData?with#disallowed&chars";
String jsplink = "Test.jsp?data="+URL.encodeQueryString(value);
Window.open(jsplink, "", "");
```

-- EDIT --

Stuff after the `?` on the URL is called the "query string". Usually it contain named parameters like `name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=....` but that's not a requirement. You can put anything after the `?` and handle it yourself. For that you need to get the complete query string as a whole using `((HttpServletRequest)request).getQueryString()`. You then need to decode and interpret it yourself.

Comment: your solution works , But cant i do something like :  String data = "someData".... Window.open("Test.jsp?"+data,"","");..... This always gives me nunll ... can you please guide